# logit with statsmodels with both binary and continuous independent variables

Tags: python, transform, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to run a logit in Python (using statsmodels) having both binary and continuous independent variables. Without transforming the variables, I cannot obtain any result, but even log-transforming them I get very huge standard deviations (notwithstanding the absence of outliers) and many nan's. What could be the problem? Is there any other way I can transform my variables in order to get more significant results?

Comment: please provide some code. No one can help you if you don't show us what you are trying to do.

Comment: You may standarize your variables.

Comment: It's not clear from your post whether you have a coding question or are just unsure about your modeling approach. The folks here can help you with a coding error you're having or strange outputs from functions, but without seeing any of your code or data, it is incredibly difficult for anyone to help you find a solution. [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) can help with statistical concept questions